# Keeping version parity between platforms

Tags: android, ios, versioning, mobile, semantic-versioning

I'm in the mobile development domain and I use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) to version my releases. I keep both versions the same as long as new builds are released for both iOS and Android platforms at the same time.

But imagine I fix a bug that appeared only on iOS. Now I have to release a new iOS build so I increase the build number *only* for the iOS version. Now the versions between the platforms are out of sync.

Do you,

1. Release a "placeholder" build for Android with the bumped up version just to keep the versions in sync?
2. Accept the fact that version numbers on separate platforms can and will be different?

How do you handle this case in your work? Or is this a non-issue?

Comment: Definitely 2. and even in case of common branch will use two different tags for versioning

Comment: @LazyBadger: if you understood #2 as an approach to let the version numbers get out-of-sync, I think this is bad advice. Not sure if you really meant that, though.

Comment: @DocBrown - we can discuss it, but I think - two versions of the *same app* with *different code- and feature-set* (due to bugfix in one) have to have two different ids

Comment: @LazyBadger: absolutely! But I understand the scenario of the OP that they have *one* common code base for two platforms, maybe with some platform specific parts. So no "different code-set", but two different apps, maybe with different feature sets available for the end-user (not from the dev's point of view), generated by the build process from the very same code base.

Comment: @DocBrown - I saw your answer to Q just now, thus - I dismiss my opinion, your solution is logically and technically a lot better and easier: mea culpa, I must to think deeper

Comment: @DocBrown then two different versions seem reasonable. What you describe is a build version. It's, essentially, the same code built twice or more. Decoupling versions is convenient because both it decouples both platforms' ALM (application lifecycle management). This is especially relevant for the company and the business strategy they want for each platform. If any. Additionally, your version strategy should fulfil the policies of both markets (Apple and Google) which might lead you to end up with different build versions on both markets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When most of your code base is shared for both platforms, I would avoid getting version numbers "out of sync", because it will bring a lot more effort for writing a coherent changelog or identifying in which version you introduced which changes. However, there is no need to release a "placeholder" build either, since this could produce unnecessary rebuild efforts for anyone who uses your library as a dependency.

Let us assume 1.4.42 was the last version released for both platforms. When new version "1.4.43" only fixes bugs for platform A, simply don't release and deploy the corresponding version to the other platform B. The next time you release a new version "1.4.44" to both platforms, users of platform B might  notice you skipped version "1.4.43" for them. But this is a no-brainer when you take care that you write into your changelog that changes from 1.4.42 to 1.4.43 were only relevant to platform A.

Of course, when both code bases are completely different, those can be seen as two products from the developers point of view, and you can go with #2, but then you would probably not bother keeping versions synchronous on any level, maintain completely different repositories and changelogs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I like this approach. I agree, normal users will hardly notice the skip but for us devs who care about the version, it's less hassle to maintain one rather than two.